# Is the current in a forward biased diode a diffusion current or a drift current?

Tags: diodes

When a diode is in equilibrium the inbuilt potential grows to stop diffusion currents. As a diode is forward biased, this inbuilt potential is overpowered providing a potential that allows current to flow. Is this current a diffusion current, as the potential barrier that prevents diffusion is now gone, or a drift current due to the positive voltage on the p side with respect to the n side?

Comment: Ask yourself: what's the force driving the charge carriers (dominantly)?